# Angular: Disable scrolling to the top when I delete an object in a list

Tags: angular, single-page-application, angular8

I have a list like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj3nl.png

When I click delete, the data will be reloaded and page scrolled to the top. I want the scroller not moving to the top. How can I do it? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```js
  employees: Observable<Employee[]>;

  reloadData(){
    this.employees = this.employeeService.getEmployeesList();
  }

  deleteEmployee(id: number){
    this.employeeService.deleteEmployee(id)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.reloadData();
      },
      error => console.log(error));
  }
```

Comment: It's because you are reloading your list every time. I suggest you instead of calling `this.reloadData()` inside the subscribe callback, you should delete it from your loaded list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest instead of reloading the whole data again, Just remove the element in that position from array. Like this

```
    deleteEmployee(id: number, index){
        this.employeeService.deleteEmployee(id)
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.employees.pipe(map(employeeList=> {
                employeeList.splice(index, 1);
                return employeeList;
            }));
          },
          error => console.log(error));
     }
```

Pass the deleting index from Html.

Comment: employees property is Observable, how can I use with that?

Comment: I am sorry. I thought employees is an arrayList, I edited my answer for an observable